# How to say 'ASMR' in Japanese?

Tags: meaning

So I just stumbled upon the word **こけし** on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/reel/CHtO3oBJqA4/). It was translated as "ASMR" (youtube trend where people speak quietly and make all kinds of "satisfying" noises). Is there anyone with enough knowledge (or guts to crawl through SNS) to explain the etymology of the word?

My guess, after throwing 'ASMR こけし' into YT, is that it comes from the modern version of the こけしdoll. Which seems to contain a jingle bell, as opposed to the usual creaking of the doll's head when turned.

If I'm wrong and **こけし** doesn't mean 'ASMR', is there a word in Japanese that does?

Note: I also presume that the cc is correct as the other few sentences were translated accurately.

Comment: I thought they just say ASMR... There is probably a long kanji compound translation for the true meaning, but I couldn't tell you what ASMR stands for off the top of my head and I would guess that's the same for Japanese people and whatever that word is.

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASMR . ASMR is simply ASMR in Japanese and I think in most other languages as well. At least in the sense it is used Youtube/etc. Whether there is some scientific term in Japanese for it, I do not know.

Comment: @Garbaz I think in Russian it is АСМР

Comment: A こけし containing a bell is not common at all. I can see why こけし is "a little bit erotic", but I have no idea why こけし was translated as "Asmr".

Comment: @Mycroft You do realize that "R" in Russian is Р, right?